# Change background-color of 1st row in the table

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, spry

Below is my table that is getting populated with spry dataset

Here is my dataset

```
var ds1 = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("/xml/data.xml", "rows/row");
```

Here is my jquery inside a method that is called on a button click

```
function addRow()
{
var newRow = new Array();
var nextID = ds1.getRowCount(); 

newRow['ds_RowID'] = nextID; 
newRow['id'] = "x"; 
newRow['name'] = "Abhishek";
newRow['country'] = "India";


ds1.dataHash[newRow['ds_RowID']] = newRow; 
ds1.data.push(newRow); 

Spry.Data.updateRegion(ds1); 

ds1.sort('name','descending'); 
ds1.setCurrentRow(newRow.ds_RowID);

$(".trEven td").css("background-color", "red");
alert($.fn.jquery);

/*$("#tableDg tbody tr:first").css({
    "background-color": "red"
});*/
}
```

Here is my table

```
<div id="cdiv" style="width:100%;" spry:region="ds1">
<table id="tableDg" 
    style="border:#2F5882 1px solid;width:100%;"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"> 

    <thead>
     <tr id="trHead" style="color :#FFFFFF;background-color: #8EA4BB"> 
         <th width="2%"><input id="chkbHead" type='checkbox' /></th>
         <th width="10%" align="center" spry:sort="name"><b>Name</b></th> 
         <th width="22%" align="center" spry:sort="host"><b>Country</b></th> 

     </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody spry:repeat="ds1">   
     <tr id="trOdd"   
     spry:if="({ds_RowNumber} % 2) != 0" onclick="ds1.setCurrentRow('{ds_RowID}');"
        style="color :#2F5882;background-color: #FFFFFF" class="{ds_OddRow}"> 
         <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbTest" class = "chkbCsm"></input></td>
         <td width="10%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;{name}</td> 
         <td width="22%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;{country}</td> 


     </tr> 

     <tr id="trEven" 
     spry:if="({ds_RowNumber} % 2) == 0" onclick="ds1.setCurrentRow('{ds_RowID}');"
        style="color :#2F5882;background-color: #EDF1F5;" class="{ds_EvenRow}"> 
         <td><input type="checkbox" class = "chkbCsm"></input></td>
         <td id="tdname" width="10%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;{name}</td> 
         <td width="22%" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;{country}</td> 

     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

Am I going wrong somewhere, please guide me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn’t be using `id`s for odd and even rows. `id` values are meant to be unique within the page.

So, I’d suggest:

```
<tr class="trOdd"
```

and:

```
<tr class="trEven"
```

and then:

```
$(".trEven")
```

If you really only want the first row in the table body to get a red background (as opposed to all the even ones), then your selector should be:

```
$("#tableDg tbody tr:first")
```

Comment: @Paul: Yes I only need first row, but this `$("#tableDg tbody tr:first").css({
  "background-color": "red"
 });` is not working, it is supposed to. but still its not working

Comment: @Paul: I provided my full javascript function for more detail

Comment: @Abhishek: hmmm, seems alright on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B3dwx/ — are you including jQuery on the page?

Comment: @Paul:Ya I looked on JSFiddle, it works. I am including jQuery because there are some other popups that are made in jquery and are working fine. The above Javascript function is also working except the jquery  part.

Comment: @Abihshek: in that case, could you post your code that *isn’t* working onto JSFiddle?

Comment: @Paul: The code seems to work on JSFiddle. I meant the code on my machine

Comment: @Abihshek: I know. I meant that you should post the code that’s on your machine, and isn’t working, onto JS Fiddle, so that we can have a proper look.

Comment: @Paul: Here is the link to JSFiddle where it is not working http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/w5VzV/1/

Comment: @Abihshek: ah, cheers. In the Fiddle, I can make it work by removing this line: `var ds1 = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("include/xml/data.xml", "rows/row");`. See http://jsfiddle.net/w5VzV/12/. So, it looks like that line is causing an error, thus preventing the rest of the JavaScript from running.

Comment: @Paul: I myself added that line, because its part of my code :) I want to know after the form is loaded with the spry dataset the 1st row should be highlighted, In my table there are only two rows in my tbody, so I m just populating it with this `ds1` the spry dataset. So that is needed. Please any other alternative?

Comment: @Abihshek: I know that line is part of your code. That line is what’s causing the code on JSFiddle not to work. If you could add whatever additional JavaScript is required to make *that* line work to JSFiddle, and if the highlighting still doesn’t work, then we might be able to help you. At the moment, we’re not looking at the same code that you’re looking at on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Works for [me (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/CQ4qw/). What problems are you experiencing?

If your use classes instead of id's, you can use something like the following:

```
$('.trEven').each(function() {
    $(this).css({"background-color": "red"});
});
```

See for reference: [jQuery API - .each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: @timboo: your link works, but it does not work on my code. I followed **Paul's** method, but that also does not seem to give me correct thing. I only want my 1st row to change its bkg-color

Comment: @Abhishek Simon The something seems to be wrong. Do you point correctly to your jQuery src? - Maybe there are some problems with other js libraries? In this case, have a look at [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict)

Comment: @timbooo: I am pointing correctly to my js, as just before executing this statement my jq function is executing other stuff. Here I am providing the function in my edited question.

Comment: @Abhishek: I thinm timbooo’s asking if you’re pointing correctly to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). The code starting with `$` is jQuery code. jQuery is a JavaScript library, so you have to include it on your page first if you want to use it. To check whether jQuery is running, what do you see when you run `alert($.fn.jquery)`?

Comment: @Paul: sorry my bad, i wrote js before, Ya I have linked to JQuery Lib in my 1st page. I added `alert($.fn.jquery);` function just after the required statement(see my JS function above) But it is still not working.

Comment: The `alert($.fn.jquery);` function showed me version of jquery `1.5.2`

Answer (score 2):

If I remember right, `<tr>` is only describing structure. `<td>` represents visual part of the table. Or this is how some browsers renders them.

Therefore `$("#trEven td").css("background-color", "red")` should work. And preferrably you should use classes instead of ids in these kind of cases where there may exist multiple instances.

Comment: I used class and `$(".trEven td").css("background-color", "red");` but this also does not seem to work. please help

Comment: Check at first, what $(".trEven td") returns or the length of it. If the wrapper set is empty, then there's the problem. Otherwise I can't figure what goes wrong. Are you having !important somewhere in the CSS, which would overwrite red?

Comment: @Abihshek: I’m afraid I’m not familiar with Spry, so I don’t know.