# Accessing form elements using jquery and DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Here is the form

```
<form method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="resulttype" value="Create">              
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>           
            <td><input type="text" id="name" value="Abhishek"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="AbhishekSimion"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="a@a.com"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Department</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="department" name="department"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="button" id="button" value="Done!"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

here is the Javascript part

```
var x = document.getElementById("name");
var email = $("input#email").val();  

var dataString = 'name='+ x + '&email=' + email;
$(function() {
$("#button").click(function() {
    callme();
    });
  });
function callme()
{
    alert(dataString);
    var msg = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/temp/AjaxPostSend",
        data: dataString,
        async: false,
        success: function(html){
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
     }).responseText;

}
```

Why do I get a message "**name=null&email=undefined**" in my alert box? What is wrong here?

Note: I am using  JQuery v1.5.2

Comment: It is possible to serialize a form and send it with ajax, instead of concatenating all values by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>At least the `email` value should work...</del>

In any case, don't create the string manually. Set `data` to an object containing the values:

```
data: {name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val()},
// or
data: $('#yourformID').serialize(),
```

This way, jQuery will take care of proper escaping.

Also note that IDs have to be unique. If you have other elements with the same IDs farther up the page, it won't work. Changes the IDs then.

**Update:**

The flow of your code is not correct. This part:

```
var x = document.getElementById("name");
var email = $("input#email").val();  

var dataString = 'name='+ x + '&email=' + email;
```

will be executed **before the page finished loading**. That means (a) that the elements are not available yet and (b) even if they were, the user would not have been able to enter any information.

You have to read the values **at the time you want to sent the form**:

```
$(function() {
    $("#button").click(callme);

    function callme() {      
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/temp/AjaxPostSend",
            data: {name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val()},
            success: function(msg){
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            }
         });
    }

});
```

Also note that

```
var msg = $.ajax({...}).responseText;
```

will not work as the Ajax request is **asynchronous**. That means `callme()` will return before the Ajax response is available. The response text is available as argument to the `success` callback.

*Correction:* I saw the `async: false` , but it seemed I had a bit error in my brain ;) In this case the above statement would work indeed. But you should avoid synchronous Ajax (should be called Sjax then) calls at it blocks the client.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var myname = $('#name').val()
var mymail = $('#email').val();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6tPtq/)

also you can use like below

**data: { name: myname, email: mymail }**

```
var msg = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",      
        url: "/temp/AjaxPostSend",
        data: { name: myname, email: mymail }
        async: false,
        success: function(html){
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
     }).responseText;
```

UPDATE

try with

`<input type="text" id="myname" name="myname" value="Abhishek"/>` and then
 `var myname = $('#myname').val()`

for sending date over POST use

```
 data: $('#yourformID').serialize(),
```

Comment: @diEcho: I get this "name=undefined&email=undefined"

Comment: how it is possible?? see the DEMO...and one more thing for good practice never set `id=name`..it lead to confusion..set something else

Comment: @diEcho: Even I tried on JSFiddle.net, here http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/AE9eB/2/ the email is working

Comment: @diEcho: It works in jsFiddle but dont know whats wrong in my machine? That is why i put this question here

Comment: why u mixing javascript method `document.getElementById();` and jQuery method `val();`. use all with `jQuery`.. and see the answer of **FlexiKling**

Comment: @diEcho: I mmixed them just for the purpose of showing that i tried both the methods. One more thing what does this `data: $('#yourformID').serialize(),` do? also  is `success: function(html){
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }` called only after the server acceptance is complete?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ and http://api.jquery.com/ajax/ `success` is called when the request was *successful* (ie. the response is not 404 or 500 or something similar). `complete` is called when the request is completed.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Then probably for my purpose I want to do something only after my request is complete. So i'll go for `complete` instead of `success`

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: That depends. Most of the time you only get a useful response when the request was successful. `success` is more often used than `complete`. But just try it.

Comment: @Felix: I tried, and my server side is recieving the data but the alert only displays `object object`. I have a situation where i'd like to call another function only after the server request is complete. how can I achieve it? also displaying the response data from server in between (probably after complete server request and i receive response from the server side)

Comment: @Felix: I tried `async:false,
            complete: function(msg){
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            }` and it works, is this good? or do you have anyother option for me?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: Making the Ajax call asynchronous defeats the purpose of having an Ajax call imo. If the alert shows `[object Object]` then this just means the data is an array. If you use Chrome or Firebug, use `console.dir(data)` to inspect the element. Just call the other function in the callback.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Thanks for the info, i'll try that, also can you look at 1 other question for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881230/change-background-color-of-1st-row-in-the-table here is the location for JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/w5VzV/8/

Comment: @Felix Kling: In http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/w5VzV/9/ after the spry data is loaded I want to highlight the 1st row.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of an input using plain JavaScript, you'll have to access the variable called `value`.

```
var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
```

Your second variable should work as expected, however it is possible to omit the input from the selector, since IDs are always unique, and it saves you a few bytes.

```
var email = $("#email").val();
```

Also, there is an easier way to send a form with ajax. Serialize the form. Notice `data: ...`

```
var msg = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/temp/AjaxPostSend",
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        async: false,
        success: function(html){
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
     }).responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var x = document.getElementById("name");
var email = $("input#email").val();
```

to

```
var x = $("#name");
var email = $("#email").val();
```

also, this part:

```
var x = $("#name");
var email = $("#email").val();  
var dataString = 'name='+ x + '&email=' + email;
```

needs to go before the callme() function call like this:

```
var dataString;
$(function() {
$("#button").click(function() {
    var x = $("#name");
    var email = $("#email").val();  
    dataString = 'name='+ x + '&email=' + email;
    callme();
    });
  });
```

Comment: I get "name=[object Object]&email=undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Because,

the value in 'x' is an object and not a string and I think the syntax of '$("input#email")' is wrong. Try `$(":input[id='email']").val()`

Comment: I get this "name=undefined&email=undefined"

Comment: try it here http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/AE9eB/2/ only email is working that too its not working in my project, i.e., on my machine

Comment: If you see the message at first time of course is null. The thing is the binding of this event will be executed before the bowser had invoked the whole page. Make a simpler method that only shows an alert executed it at event document.ready.

Comment: I got also the Message 'name=[object Object]&email=undefined'. What I sait is, the method 'getElemntsById()' returns an object not a string. What you want is 'x.value'.

Comment: see @Felix Kling's reply, There is a good answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why email is giving you undefined value, but for name it should be like the following:

```
var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
```

OR

```
var x = $('#name').val();
```